# Обработка нажатия на кнопку

Tags: php

Как сделать обработку события нажатия на кнопку? Как я понял нету такого:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Как сделать, чтобы именно при нажатии на нужную кнопку, срабатывал определённый php код?

Answer (score 13):

Самое главное - понять, что ваша **кнопка у пользователя**, а **обработчик - на сервере**. И рисоваться кнопка может в одном файле, а обрабатываться в другом. Всё это **отдельно**.

**Первый** вариант, кнопку можно представить так как писали другие:

```
<form action="/скрипт/который/будет/обрабатывать/эту_форму.php" method="POST">
     <input name="myActionName" type="submit" value="Выполнить" />
</form>
```

Код обработчика:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['myActionName'])
    {
        // делаете что угодно
    }
?>
```

Или **другое** решение. В век расцвета AJAX можно ведь и так:

```
<button id="myActionButton">Выполни</button>
<script>
    $('#myActionButton').click(function(){
        $.post(
            "/скрипт/который/будет/обрабатывать/эту_форму.php", 
            { myActionName: "Выполнить" } 
        );
    });
</script>
```

Но для этого надо еще библиотеку jQuery подключить.

Обработчик тот же. О подробностях по работе с формами, что такое POST/GET или AJAX информации море.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="тут_ваш.php">
<input type='button' value="KNOPKA">
</form>
```

Comment: Да а как теперь указать какой именно блок будет выполняться?

Вот у меня такой код:

                <?php
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO t_quest") VALUES('Как дела?');
    ?>

Как сделать что бы он не сразу выполнялся, а именно после того как была нажата кнопка.

Answer (score 0):

А чем вам не нравится такой подход:

```
<form method="POST">
 <button name="myActionName" type="submit" value="0">0</button>
 <button name="myActionName" type="submit" value="1">1</button>
 <button name="myActionName" type="submit" value="2">2</button>
 <button name="myActionName" type="submit" value="3">3</button>
</form>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['myActionName'])) {
        switch ($_POST['myActionName']) {
        case '0':
            include_once 'you_file1.php';
            break;
        case '1':
            include_once 'you_file2.php';
            break;
        case '2':
            include_once 'you_file3.php';
            break;
        case '3':
            include_once 'you_file4.php';
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Дай кнопке имя  (пропиши атрибут name) и укажи его ниже вместо многоточия.
при нажатии сработает файл test.php

```
if (isset($_POST["....."])) {
require "test.php";}
```

Comment: этот код прописывай в обработчике формы в которой находится кнопка

Comment: вы можете нажать "править" (находится под ответом) и добавить в него изменения - а не оставлять их в комментариях.